# A question about the CDF of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ be a probability space and $X:\Omega \to B$, where $(B, \mathcal B)$ is a Banach measure space. Consider $P_X$ the probability distribution of $X$ which is nothing more that push-forward probability induced by $X$: $(B, \mathcal B, P_X)$. I know that if $B = \mathbb R$, then we have the CDF:
$$F_X(x)= P_X((-\infty,x]), \quad x \in \mathbb R$$
This CDF satisfies a series of properties that define it as a CDF. Moreover, if $X$ is absolutely continuous (in fact, $P_X$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure $\lambda$), this is equivalent to say that there is a density function, $f$, such that:
$$P_X(A)= \int_{A} f d \lambda, \quad F_X(x)= \int_{-\infty}^x f d\lambda.$$

For any probability distribution there exists a CDF, and, for any CDF $F$, there exists a probability distribution. I imagine that the definition of CDF is independent of a random variable $X$. So I think that the intuition of the proof that for every CDF there is a probability distribution (of a random variable) goes through the construction of a random variable $X$.

So, I have two question:

1. If $B$ is a more general Banach Space (for example, some inifinite dimensional space). Can I define the CDF of $X$?
2. Finally, can I define the notion of density?

Comment: NO and NO. You don't even have a reference measure (like Lebesgue measure) on  a general Banach space so the second question does not even make snsee.

Comment: I would like to understand better. Why is a reference measure needed to define a CDF?

Comment: Reference measure needed for second question.  Definition of  CDF requires an ordering which does not exist in a general Banach space.